# What is the background of God's Demon by Wayne Barlowe?

Tags: christian

I've read [*God's Demon*](http://www.godsdemon.com/) by [Wayne Barlowe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Barlowe), and I would like to know more about the characters. The story follows demons in Hell after the Fall. The most important characters are  [Lilith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith), [Lucifer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer), [Beelzebub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub) and Sargatanas. Barlowe didn't invent the names or the general setting, of course, but I don't know how much of the specifics are by him and how much are from preexisting settings.

> Lucifer led the rebellion of angels against the Throne, and disappeared after the Fall. Lilith was already in Hell at the time of the Fall, because of not-fully-specified disagreements with the Throne. She was briefly Lucifer's consort, then she was Beelzebub's, by force, after Lucifer's disappearance. Sargatanas regretted the Fall and rebelled against Beelzebub, lord of Hell. The book is the story of Sargatanas's rebellion and redemption.

Are there prior works that Barlowe specifically draws upon? I don't mean the general mythology, but works with specific elements such as Lilith or Sargatanas's role, political differences between demons, …

Comment: There are politics in Dilbert's office. How can demons possibly not have it? :))))

Answer (score 1):

Some of the demon characters are based on the [Ars Goetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goetia#The_Ars_Goetia) [demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demons_in_the_Ars_Goetia) from the [*Lesser Key of Solomon (Lemegeton)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lesser_Key_of_Solomon#The_Seventy-Two_Demons), but Barlowe puts his own spin on them.